# Combine every single protobuf file into one "combined.proto"

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I've looked extensively for good solutions to this question. I'm fine with writing a script.

I'd like to combine every single .proto file I have here into a single "combined.proto" for various reasons.

The other answers I've found on here haven't matched my problem - some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that a single proto file can include only one `syntax` and one `package` entry so, your files would all need to be the same syntax (`proto2` or `proto3`) and be part of the same package. Then, you may be able to simply concatenate all your proto files and then (to avoid parsing multiline message defs) remove all non-initial occurrences of `syntax`, `package`, `option` etc.